Is there a way to tell FindShortestTour to avoid backtracking when connecting points to form a closed, but possiblely non-convex, curve?
Among a set of points, I want to find a closed curve.
It is not required for the curve to go through all the points, only that the curve goes through as many points as possible. These points are expected form a closed curve, but it may be a non-convex closed curve, as shown in the picture below.
While FindShortestTour can help me find such a curve,
it ends up backtracking in many places.
Is there a way to tell FindShortestTour to avoid backtracking as much as possible,
such that if it detects backtracking, it will incur a penalty.
I guess this is similar to how the built-in examples of FindShortestTour in the documentation penalize crossing a river?
Below is my code.
Thanks :)
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;

{dist, order} = 
  FindShortestTour[datDirty, PerformanceGoal :> "Quality", 
   DirectedEdges -> False];
dat = Part[datDirty, order];


Animate[
 Show[
  (*ListPlot[dat,PlotStyle->Gray,ImageSize->500],*)
  ListLinePlot[dat[[1 ;; i]], PlotStyle -> Blue],
  ListPlot[{dat[[i]]}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}]
  ], {i, 1, Length@dat, 1}]

datDirty = {{-303.509891512444`, -207.272727272727`}, \
{-302.999361837907`, -214.545454545455`}, {-301.978302488832`, \
-243.636363636364`}, {-301.467772814295`, -250.909090909091`}, \
{-297.894065092533`, -338.181818181818`}, {-296.362476068921`, \
-345.454545454545`}, {-293.809827696235`, -349.090909090909`}, \
{-293.299298021697`, -356.363636363636`}, {-291.767708998085`, 
    330.909090909091`}, {-290.746649649011`, -392.727272727273`}, \
{-288.704530950862`, 
    341.818181818182`}, {-286.662412252712`, -392.727272727273`}, \
{-284.620293554563`, 
    374.545454545455`}, {-283.088704530951`, -410.909090909091`}, \
{-282.067645181876`, 374.545454545455`}, {-281.046585832801`, 
    370.909090909091`}, {-279.514996809189`, 
    378.181818181818`}, {-277.983407785578`, -418.181818181818`}, \
{-275.941289087428`, -425.454545454545`}, {-274.920229738353`, 
    396.363636363636`}, {-273.899170389279`, -447.272727272727`}, \
{-272.878111040204`, 407.272727272727`}, {-272.367581365667`, 
    392.727272727273`}, {-270.325462667518`, -454.545454545455`}, \
{-268.793873643905`, -450.909090909091`}, {-267.262284620294`, 
    410.909090909091`}, {-266.241225271219`, 
    410.909090909091`}, {-265.220165922144`, -461.818181818182`}, \
{-263.688576898532`, 
    429.090909090909`}, {-261.646458200383`, -461.818181818182`}, \
{-260.625398851308`, 418.181818181818`}, {-259.604339502234`, 
    429.090909090909`}, {-258.072750478622`, 
    440.`}, {-256.54116145501`, 
    425.454545454545`}, {-255.009572431398`, 
    443.636363636364`}, {-253.477983407786`, 
    429.090909090909`}, {-252.456924058711`, 
    432.727272727273`}, {-251.435864709636`, 
    443.636363636364`}, {-249.904275686024`, -480.`}, \
{-248.372686662412`, 454.545454545455`}, {-246.8410976388`, 
    436.363636363636`}, {-245.309508615188`, 
    454.545454545455`}, {-243.777919591576`, 
    465.454545454545`}, {-241.22527121889`, -480.`}, \
{-239.693682195278`, 
    454.545454545455`}, {-237.141033822591`, -494.545454545455`}, \
{-235.098915124442`, -490.909090909091`}, {-233.056796426292`, \
-512.727272727273`}, {-231.014677728143`, -498.181818181818`}, \
{-229.993618379068`, 
    461.818181818182`}, {-227.951499680919`, -498.181818181818`}, \
{-226.419910657307`, -512.727272727273`}, {-224.888321633695`, 
    476.363636363636`}, {-222.846202935546`, -501.818181818182`}, \
{-220.804084237396`, -516.363636363636`}, {-218.761965539247`, 
    465.454545454545`}, {-217.740906190172`, 
    487.272727272727`}, {-216.20931716656`, -516.363636363636`}, \
{-214.677728142948`, -509.090909090909`}, {-212.635609444799`, \
-512.727272727273`}, {-211.104020421187`, 
    472.727272727273`}, {-209.572431397575`, 
    476.363636363636`}, {-207.530312699426`, 
    483.636363636364`}, {-204.977664326739`, 
    480.`}, {-203.956604977664`, 
    480.`}, {-201.403956604978`, -534.545454545455`}, \
{-199.872367581366`, -527.272727272727`}, {-197.830248883216`, 
    483.636363636364`}, {-196.298659859604`, 
    501.818181818182`}, {-194.767070835992`, 
    483.636363636364`}, {-192.724952137843`, 
    501.818181818182`}, {-191.193363114231`, 
    501.818181818182`}, {-189.661774090619`, 
    483.636363636364`}, {-188.130185067007`, 
    509.090909090909`}, {-186.598596043395`, -538.181818181818`}, \
{-184.556477345246`, 512.727272727273`}, {-182.003828972559`, 
    501.818181818182`}, {-179.451180599872`, -523.636363636364`}, \
{-176.898532227186`, 501.818181818182`}, {-174.345883854499`, 
    501.818181818182`}, {-171.793235481812`, 
    505.454545454545`}, {-169.240587109126`, 
    498.181818181818`}, {-167.708998085514`, 
    516.363636363636`}, {-165.156349712827`, 
    512.727272727273`}, {-162.60370134014`, 
    509.090909090909`}, {-160.051052967454`, -552.727272727273`}, \
{-157.498404594767`, 
    509.090909090909`}, {-155.456285896618`, -552.727272727273`}, \
{-153.924696873006`, -549.090909090909`}, {-152.393107849394`, 
    505.454545454545`}, {-150.350989151244`, 
    520.`}, {-148.819400127632`, 
    523.636363636364`}, {-147.28781110402`, 
    505.454545454545`}, {-145.245692405871`, -541.818181818182`}, \
{-144.224633056796`, 
    530.909090909091`}, {-142.182514358647`, -538.181818181818`}, \
{-139.62986598596`, -541.818181818182`}, {-137.077217613274`, 
    527.272727272727`}, {-134.524569240587`, 
    523.636363636364`}, {-129.419272495214`, 
    520.`}, {-127.887683471602`, 
    523.636363636364`}, {-126.35609444799`, 
    516.363636363636`}, {-125.335035098915`, 
    530.909090909091`}, {-123.292916400766`, -563.636363636364`}, \
{-121.761327377154`, 
    527.272727272727`}, {-120.229738353542`, -560.`}, \
{-118.187619655392`, -563.636363636364`}, {-116.65603063178`, \
-549.090909090909`}, {-115.124441608168`, -563.636363636364`}, \
{-112.571793235482`, 
    520.`}, {-110.019144862795`, -560.`}, {-108.99808551372`, \
-549.090909090909`}, {-106.955966815571`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{-105.424377791959`, -563.636363636364`}, {-103.892788768347`, 
    523.636363636364`}, {-101.850670070198`, -567.272727272727`}, \
{-100.319081046586`, -570.909090909091`}, {-98.7874920229738`, \
-560.`}, {-96.7453733248245`, -560.`}, {-95.2137843012125`, 
    527.272727272727`}, {-93.6821952776005`, -560.`}, \
{-91.6400765794511`, -563.636363636364`}, {-90.1084875558392`, 
    534.545454545455`}, {-88.5768985322272`, 
    527.272727272727`}, {-86.5347798340778`, 
    523.636363636364`}, {-85.0031908104659`, -567.272727272727`}, \
{-83.4716017868539`, -563.636363636364`}, {-81.9400127632418`, 
    530.909090909091`}, {-79.8978940650925`, -570.909090909091`}, \
{-78.3663050414805`, -560.`}, {-76.8347160178685`, 
    538.181818181818`}, {-74.7925973197192`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{-73.2610082961072`, -556.363636363636`}, {-71.7294192724952`, \
-556.363636363636`}, {-69.6873005743459`, 
    545.454545454545`}, {-68.1557115507339`, -574.545454545455`}, \
{-66.6241225271219`, -574.545454545455`}, {-64.5820038289726`, \
-563.636363636364`}, {-63.0504148053606`, -570.909090909091`}, \
{-61.5188257817485`, 
    534.545454545455`}, {-59.4767070835992`, -560.`}, \
{-57.9451180599872`, -563.636363636364`}, {-56.4135290363752`, 
    549.090909090909`}, {-54.8819400127632`, -563.636363636364`}, \
{-53.8608806636886`, 534.545454545455`}, {-52.3292916400766`, 
    549.090909090909`}, {-51.3082322910019`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{-49.7766432673899`, -563.636363636364`}, {-48.7555839183152`, 
    534.545454545455`}, {-47.2239948947032`, -560.`}, \
{-45.6924058710913`, -556.363636363636`}, {-43.6502871729419`, 
    545.454545454545`}, {-42.1186981493299`, -567.272727272727`}, \
{-40.5871091257179`, -560.`}, {-38.5449904275686`, 
    549.090909090909`}, {-37.0134014039565`, -560.`}, \
{-35.4818123803446`, -563.636363636364`}, {-33.9502233567326`, \
-556.363636363636`}, {-32.4186343331206`, -560.`}, \
{-31.3975749840459`, 
    545.454545454545`}, {-29.8659859604339`, -567.272727272727`}, \
{-28.8449266113593`, -560.`}, {-27.3133375877472`, -560.`}, \
{-25.7817485641352`, -556.363636363636`}, {-24.2501595405233`, \
-563.636363636364`}, {-22.7185705169113`, 
    552.727272727273`}, {-21.6975111678366`, 
    560.`}, {-20.1659221442246`, -578.181818181818`}, \
{-19.1448627951499`, -574.545454545455`}, {-18.1238034460753`, 
    556.363636363636`}, {-16.5922144224633`, -574.545454545455`}, \
{-15.5711550733886`, -570.909090909091`}, {-14.0395660497767`, \
-560.`}, {-11.9974473516273`, -560.`}, {-10.9763880025527`, \
-556.363636363636`}, {-9.44479897894064`, -560.`}, \
{-8.42373962986596`, 552.727272727273`}, {-7.40268028079129`, 
    552.727272727273`}, {-5.87109125717927`, 
    560.`}, {-4.8500319081046`, 
    563.636363636364`}, {-3.82897255903003`, -563.636363636364`}, \
{-2.29738353541802`, -563.636363636364`}, {-1.27632418634334`, 
    560.`}, {0.255264837268669`, 
    545.454545454545`}, {1.27632418634334`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{2.29738353541802`, 
    545.454545454545`}, {2.80791320995536`, -567.272727272727`}, \
{4.33950223356737`, 
    563.636363636364`}, {5.36056158264205`, -560.`}, \
{6.89215060625395`, 
    556.363636363636`}, {7.91320995532863`, -560.`}, \
{9.44479897894064`, -567.272727272727`}, {10.4658583280153`, \
-574.545454545455`}, {11.48691767709`, 
    552.727272727273`}, {13.018506700702`, -563.636363636364`}, \
{14.550095724314`, 556.363636363636`}, {16.5922144224633`, 
    556.363636363636`}, {18.1238034460753`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{19.6553924696873`, -563.636363636364`}, {21.6975111678366`, \
-563.636363636364`}, {23.2291001914487`, -574.545454545455`}, \
{24.7606892150607`, -560.`}, {26.2922782386727`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{28.3343969368219`, 
    560.`}, {29.8659859604339`, -570.909090909091`}, \
{31.3975749840459`, -556.363636363636`}, {33.4396936821953`, 
    556.363636363636`}, {34.9712827058073`, 
    556.363636363636`}, {36.5028717294193`, 
    552.727272727273`}, {38.5449904275686`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{40.0765794511806`, -556.363636363636`}, {41.6081684747926`, \
-556.363636363636`}, {43.6502871729419`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{45.181876196554`, -560.`}, {46.713465220166`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{48.7555839183152`, -570.909090909091`}, {50.2871729419272`, \
-570.909090909091`}, {51.8187619655392`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{53.8608806636886`, -560.`}, {55.3924696873006`, -560.`}, \
{56.9240587109126`, -556.363636363636`}, {58.9661774090619`, 
    563.636363636364`}, {60.4977664326739`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{62.0293554562859`, -560.`}, {64.0714741544352`, 
    560.`}, {65.6030631780473`, 
    556.363636363636`}, {67.1346522016593`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{69.1767708998085`, -560.`}, {70.7083599234205`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{72.2399489470325`, -560.`}, {74.2820676451819`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{75.8136566687939`, -560.`}, {77.3452456924059`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{79.3873643905551`, -560.`}, {80.9189534141672`, 
    552.727272727273`}, {82.4505424377792`, -570.909090909091`}, \
{84.4926611359285`, -570.909090909091`}, {86.0242501595405`, 
    552.727272727273`}, {87.5558391831526`, -560.`}, \
{89.5979578813019`, 
    570.909090909091`}, {91.1295469049138`, -563.636363636364`}, \
{92.6611359285258`, 552.727272727273`}, {94.7032546266752`, 
    560.`}, {96.2348436502872`, 
    563.636363636364`}, {97.7664326738992`, -567.272727272727`}, \
{100.319081046586`, -563.636363636364`}, {102.871729419272`, 
    570.909090909091`}, {105.424377791959`, 
    556.363636363636`}, {107.977026164646`, -570.909090909091`}, \
{110.529674537332`, -560.`}, {113.082322910019`, -567.272727272727`}, \
{115.634971282706`, 560.`}, {118.187619655392`, 
    552.727272727273`}, {120.740268028079`, 
    552.727272727273`}, {123.292916400766`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{125.335035098915`, -560.`}, {127.887683471602`, 
    560.`}, {130.440331844288`, -560.`}, {132.992980216975`, \
-563.636363636364`}, {135.545628589662`, -563.636363636364`}, \
{138.098276962348`, 
    560.`}, {140.650925335035`, -567.272727272727`}, \
{143.203573707722`, 
    567.272727272727`}, {145.245692405871`, -563.636363636364`}, \
{147.798340778558`, -563.636363636364`}, {150.350989151244`, \
-549.090909090909`}, {153.414167198468`, -574.545454545455`}, \
{155.456285896618`, -563.636363636364`}, {156.98787492023`, 
    563.636363636364`}, {159.029993618379`, -541.818181818182`}, \
{160.561582641991`, -552.727272727273`}, {161.582641991066`, -560.`}, \
{163.114231014678`, -556.363636363636`}, {164.135290363752`, \
-545.454545454545`}, {165.666879387364`, -556.363636363636`}, \
{166.687938736439`, -560.`}, {168.219527760051`, -549.090909090909`}, \
{169.240587109126`, 560.`}, {170.772176132738`, 
    560.`}, {172.814294830887`, -552.727272727273`}, \
{174.345883854499`, -545.454545454545`}, {175.877472878111`, \
-552.727272727273`}, {177.91959157626`, -545.454545454545`}, \
{179.451180599872`, -549.090909090909`}, {180.982769623484`, \
-549.090909090909`}, {183.024888321634`, -552.727272727273`}, \
{184.556477345246`, -552.727272727273`}, {186.088066368858`, \
-541.818181818182`}, {188.130185067007`, -549.090909090909`}, \
{189.661774090619`, -545.454545454545`}, {191.193363114231`, 
    541.818181818182`}, {192.724952137843`, -552.727272727273`}, \
{193.746011486918`, 
    549.090909090909`}, {195.27760051053`, -545.454545454545`}, \
{196.298659859604`, -538.181818181818`}, {197.830248883216`, \
-538.181818181818`}, {198.851308232291`, -534.545454545455`}, \
{199.872367581366`, 549.090909090909`}, {201.403956604978`, 
    549.090909090909`}, {202.425015954052`, -538.181818181818`}, \
{203.956604977664`, 545.454545454545`}, {204.977664326739`, 
    545.454545454545`}, {206.509253350351`, -530.909090909091`}, \
{207.530312699426`, -527.272727272727`}, {209.061901723038`, 
    545.454545454545`}, {210.082961072112`, 
    549.090909090909`}, {211.614550095724`, 
    545.454545454545`}, {213.146139119336`, -523.636363636364`}, \
{214.677728142948`, 
    541.818181818182`}, {216.20931716656`, -538.181818181818`}, \
{218.25143586471`, 545.454545454545`}, {219.783024888322`, 
    534.545454545455`}, {221.314613911934`, -520.`}, \
{222.846202935546`, 534.545454545455`}, {224.377791959158`, 
    530.909090909091`}, {226.419910657307`, -530.909090909091`}, \
{227.440970006382`, 534.545454545455`}, {228.462029355456`, 
    520.`}, {228.972559029994`, 520.`}, {230.504148053606`, 
    509.090909090909`}, {233.056796426292`, 
    516.363636363636`}, {235.609444798979`, -527.272727272727`}, \
{239.18315252074`, 
    516.363636363636`}, {243.777919591576`, -501.818181818182`}, \
{246.330567964263`, -498.181818181818`}, {248.88321633695`, 
    501.818181818182`}, {251.435864709636`, -505.454545454545`}, \
{253.477983407786`, 
    494.545454545455`}, {254.49904275686`, -494.545454545455`}, \
{257.051691129547`, 
    501.818181818182`}, {259.093809827696`, -509.090909090909`}, \
{259.604339502234`, 
    498.181818181818`}, {261.135928525846`, -498.181818181818`}, \
{261.646458200383`, -487.272727272727`}, {262.667517549458`, \
-490.909090909091`}, {264.709636247607`, 
    465.454545454545`}, {265.730695596682`, -487.272727272727`}, \
{266.751754945756`, -469.090909090909`}, {267.262284620294`, 
    458.181818181818`}, {268.283343969368`, -469.090909090909`}, \
{269.304403318443`, -469.090909090909`}, {270.835992342055`, \
-483.636363636364`}, {272.367581365667`, -483.636363636364`}, \
{273.899170389279`, -476.363636363636`}, {274.920229738354`, \
-465.454545454545`}, {276.451818761966`, -472.727272727273`}, \
{277.983407785577`, -469.090909090909`}, {279.514996809189`, 
    447.272727272727`}, {281.557115507339`, 
    440.`}, {283.599234205488`, -447.272727272727`}, {285.1308232291`,
     425.454545454545`}, {286.151882578175`, -447.272727272727`}, \
{288.194001276324`, 
    414.545454545455`}, {289.725590299936`, -410.909090909091`}, \
{291.257179323548`, -400.`}, {292.278238672623`, 
    381.818181818182`}, {293.299298021697`, -385.454545454545`}, \
{295.341416719847`, 356.363636363636`}, {296.873005743459`, 
    349.090909090909`}, {297.894065092534`, 
    349.090909090909`}, {299.425654116145`, 
    320.`}, {301.978302488832`, 
    290.909090909091`}, {302.488832163369`, 
    258.181818181818`}, {302.999361837907`, 
    221.818181818182`}, {304.020421186981`, 
    170.909090909091`}, {304.530950861519`, 181.818181818182`}};




Please post the data of the second picture.

Thanks for your attention. This is the data from my second plot (链接: https://pan.baidu.com/s/1HrOnv7k7j_d1-WF7N3jPiQ?pwd=yzd7 提取码: yzd7 ), but I think the data from the first plot better illustrates my problem. The idea is to follow a closed curve, without backtracking - if going clockwise, maintain the clockwise direction. This closed curve should pass through as many of my data points as possible. I'm quite confused- why did someone suggest closing this problem? Did I do something wrong?

What you want is not clear. What is the definition of "Back tracking"? The answer given in the MMA document for the points  {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}} is acceptable or not.

Thanks. Is this one of the reasons to suggest to close my question? I had thought it is the convex thing. Anyway, could you please tell me where can I see the reasons for suggesting colosing my question? By the way, it is hard for me, as a non native English speaker, to understand this scentence: "The answer given in the MMA document for the points {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}} is acceptable or not. "

I'm not suggesting to close your question. I just want to clarify what you want so that you would get better answer from others. My question is whether you accept or not the solution given in the Help Document, that is, "Examples > Basic Examples" section of Wolfram Documentation Center:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour.html.en

@xinxinguo I don't think that smoothing the shortest tour is what you are looking for. Probably  you need a modified FindShortestTour routine which considers the slope of the elements too.

@UlrichNeumann Thanks! Yes, I would like a smooth tour, maybe by restricting the slopes of points.

Maybe use MovingAverage or Partition+Mean to smoothing the dat after  FindShortestTour.
Clear[k, data2];
k = 6;
data2 = Append[#, First@#] &@(Mean /@ Partition[dat, k, 1, -1]);
ListLinePlot[{dat, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.6], Red}]



Does your "curve go through as many points as possible"?

Not sure how you define "backtracking". It appears that you define it as the requirement to go to ever-increasing polar angles which may in cases contradict the requirement for "shortest" tour I think. If that's the case, then a simple polar transform, sort by angle and then inverse polar transform should give you what you need (but note, there is absolutely no element of shortness in this path):
transformed = (datDirty /. {a_, b_} :> AbsArg[a + I  b] // 
     SortBy[Last]) /. {c_, d_} :> c {Cos[d], Sin[d]};
ListLinePlot@transformed



Not (yet) an answer, only a solution idea.
To  solve your problem we have to redefine FindShortestTour in such a way , that the distance function includes points and angle of lineelements.
dist[p_  ] := 
 Block[{tag = 1 , n = Length[p], 
   pn = Join[ p[[-2 ;; -1]] , p, p[[1 ;; 2]] ] , 
   angle = Function[{a, b}, 
     If[a . b == 0 && Det[{a, b}] == 0, 0, 
      ArcTan[a . b, Det[{a, b}]]]]  (*signed vectorangle between a,
   b*)
    (*,angle=Function[{a,b},ArcTan[a.b,Det[{a,b}]]]*)
   , faktor = 1/2 + tag Boole[#^2 > (Pi/2)^2]  (#^2 - (Pi/2)^2)^2 & 
    },
    Sum[ (faktor[
         angle[pn[[ i + 1]] - pn[[i ]], pn[[i ]] - pn[[i - 1 ]]]] + 
        faktor[angle[pn[[ i ]] - pn[[i - 1 ]], 
          pn[[i - 1 ]] - pn[[i - 2 ]]]])  Sqrt[# . #] &[
    pn[[i]] - pn[[i - 1]]] , {i, 3, n + 2}]
  ]

If the angle of neighboring lineelements is much greater than 0 dist returns a norm much greater than the length of the line element.
Simple Redefinition of FindShortetsTour
findSmoothTour = 
 Function[p, Block[{n = Length[p ],  pn, n1, n2, distp, distpn},
   distp = dist[p ];
   {n1, n2} = RandomSample[Range[1, Length[p]], 2] ;
   If[n1 < n2,
    pn = Join[p[[;; n1 - 1]], Reverse[p[[n1 ;; n2]]], p[[n2 + 1 ;;]]],
    pn = Join[p[[;; n2 - 1]], Reverse[p[[n2 ;; n1]]], p[[n1 + 1 ;;]]]
    ];
   distpn = dist[pn ];
   If[distpn < distp, pn, p]
   ] ]

Currently this approach isn't fast, though we reduce size of tourdata
datDirtyn=RandomSample[DatDirty, 200]  ;
{dist, order} = FindShortestTour[datDirtyn ];
dat = Part[datDirty, order];

test
datG = Nest[findSmoothTour, dat    , 5000  ];
{ dist[dat], dist[datG]} (* {7528.7, 6463.85} *)

Approach gives an improvement of dist but tour doesn't look much better.
Any ideas how to improve this approach?

If I correctly understand your aim, the following does the job.
Region[RegionBoundary[ConvexHullRegion[datDirty]]]



Thank you very much. That's a very nice method. But the region formed by my set of points may not necessarily be convex. What should I do in that case?

According to your " I want to find a closed curve. It is not required for the curve to go through all the points, only that the curve goes through as many points as possible, especially the points near the left and right sides", a non-convex region formed by FindShortestTour[datDirty] as a polygon is replaced by a convex region ConvexHullRegion[datDirty]

If my poor English has caused any misunderstanding, I sincerely apologize. I have modified the question to emphasize that the line connecting my data points may form a non-convex closed curve. Thank you again!
